# Not validating result set size using Java

Tags: java, jdbc

This is a weird issue. I know I'm making a small mistake but not able to figure it out what exactly in it.

I'm executing one query and it has result set. First I'm validating if it doesn't has records then set one of the DTO attribute to false. If it has records, then iterate and do some business.

```
rs = partyPreparedStatement.executeQuery();

if(!rs.next()) { // It has records, but I'm checking with ! operator to make sure it goes to false or true. 
    purchaseDto.setPOIssued(false);
} else {
    while (rs.next()) { // It has records, but still its not going to execute business
        // Do some business here.               
        break;
    }                
}
```

Is the design correct?

Comment: do-while would be the best approach here

Comment: If you plan to break out of the loop at the first iteration, why are looping at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data *is* returned you will be ignoring the first row.

The first call to `next()` will already position the ResultSet to the first row (if there is data). But you don't do anything with that row, you immediately call `next()` again (in the `while` condition) thus ignoring the first row completely.

*How* you solve this problem is a matter of taste. I personally would simply count the number of rows processed:

If you only want to process the first row, you don't need a while to begin with:

```
rs = partyPreparedStatement.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
   purchaseDto.setPOIssued(true);
   // process the data here
} else {
   purchaseDto.setPOIssued(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. YCF solution is more faster?which one do you think?

Comment: @Aliy: the performance aspect is negligible if not so say irrelevant. But if you are **only** going to use the first row the `while` loop will confuse people reading your code. Make your intentions clear by not using a loop to process a single row.

Comment: Since I get lot of records, I need to loop.

Comment: But you said: "*I just want the first row to be read*". And if you do want all rows, then why are you breaking out of the loop after processing the first row?

Comment: I got your point. I used it because I will break the loop, so other rows are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You move the cursor two times so instead you can use `do{}while` loop :

```
if (!rs.next()) {
    purchaseDto.setPOIssued(false);
} else {
    do {
        // Do some business here.               
        break;
    } while (rs.next());
}
```

Comment: But, where do u want me to add purchaseDto.setPOIssued(false);?

Comment: what did you mean @Aliy ?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks YCF_L

Answer (score 0):

set the value default to `false` and in the loop to `true`

```
purchaseDto.setPOIssued(false);

while (rs.next()) { // It has records, but still its not going to execute business
        // Do some business here.               
       purchaseDto.setPOIssued(true);

        break;
    }
```